# Conditionally use default kwarg in method

Tags: python

I'm using a method that has lots of kwargs, and I want to conditionally add an arg

```py
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch, RequestsHttpConnection

internal = True

es = Elasticsearch(
    hosts=[{'host': host, 'port': 443}],
    http_auth = awsauth,
    use_ssl=True,
    verify_certs=True,
    connection_class=RequestsHttpConnection,
    ca_certs="/path/to/internal/certs" if internal else 'what to put here?'
)
```

I want to act as though the `ca_certs` arg was never provided.

How can I do this without doing two separate `Elasticsearch()` methods

Comment: What’s the default value of that arg? Probably `None`…?

Comment: Ahh in [this case](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-py/blob/f4447bf996bdee47a0eb4c736bd39dea20a4486e/elasticsearch/connection/http_requests.py#L75), yes it's `None`. Thanks!